# RetryWhen and exception logic

Tags: c#, exception, system.reactive

I have been looking at implementing a basic retry logic for a simple network stream. The idea is that there are three types of exceptions to handle:

- Transient exceptions, should reconnect and retry
- Permanent error connection, should propagate and let process die
- Exceptions that should be swallowed and should complete the observable

While sketching this up, I end up with something like

```
var retriedObservable = observable.RetryWhen(x => x.SelectMany(ex =>
{
    if (ex is ShouldCompleteException)
    {
        return Observable.Return<Exception>(null);
    }
    else if (ex is TransientNetworkException)
    {
        return Observable.Return(ex).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
    else
    {
        return Observable.Throw<Exception>(ex);
    }
}).TakeUntil(ex => ex == null));
```

**Edit: This example is highly simplified, showing only the three typical error handling patterns I see in my code. In the real world, there's a lot more to it of course.**

The code works but looks overly complicated, and I'm not sure if the special 'null' value will hit me in the face at some point.

I also tried combinations of `.Where()` and `.Merge()`, but the code quickly becomes unreadable.

Is there a cleaner way (i.e. more canonical) to accomplish this basic error handling?

Answer (score 2):

This helps a little:

```
var retriedObservable2 = observable.RetryWhen(exStream => Observable.Merge(
    exStream.OfType<ShouldCompleteException>().Select(_ => (Exception)null),
    exStream.NotOfType(typeof(ShouldCompleteException)).OfType<TransientNetworkException>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
    exStream.NotOfTypes(typeof(ShouldCompleteException), typeof(TransientNetworkException)).SelectMany(e => Observable.Throw<Exception>(e))
).TakeUntil(ex => ex == null));
```

Which uses the following extension messages:

```
public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<TSource> NotOfType<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Type t)
    {
        return source.Where(o => !t.IsInstanceOfType(o));
    }

    public static IObservable<TSource> NotOfTypes<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, params Type[] ts)
    {
        return source.Where(o => ts.All(t => !t.IsInstanceOfType(o)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already great libraries for this, like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). But, if you want to implement your own, you can do something like the following.

You can create a `RetryPolicyHandler` class. Also, you can abstract it with an interface and use with any of the IoC containers if you want. Add a method like `RetryExecuteAsync` with the following implementation.

```
public async Task RetryExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
{
    int retryCount = default(int);
    int maxNumberOfRetries = 5; // Or get from settings

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            await action().ConfigureAwait(false);

            break;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            // Something specific about this exception
            if (++retryCount > maxNumberOfRetries)
                throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
            if (++retryCount > maxNumberOfRetries)
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this.

```
await this.retryPolicyHandler.RetryExecuteAsync(async () =>  
{
    // Whatever code you want to retry
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can also create other specific methods if you want. For instance, `ExecuteDeadlockRetryAsync` with catching `SqlException` or `ExecuteHttpCallRetryAsync` for handling `HttpRequestException` and handle them in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Polly, looks useful! But even given a library, one would have to implement this in Rx. I was more interested in how to do this specifically in Rx, rather than a good implementation for it.

Comment: [Polly doesn't integrate with Rx easily](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/134)